# Tricky inequality on norms of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Let $v_0=(v_{0x},0),v_1=(v1x,0),w_0=r_0e^{i\theta_0},w_1=r_1e^{i\theta_1}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be any four non-zero vectors such that:

- $v_{0x}>0$ and $v_{1x}>0$
- $0<\theta_0<\pi$ and $0<\theta_1<\pi$
- the following inequalities are satisfied:
  $$\displaystyle{\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}> \frac{||w_1||}{||w_0||}}\quad \textit{and }\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}> \frac{||v_1+w_1||}{||v_0+w_0||}$$

Now define, for every $t\in [0,1]$, the following vectors:

$$\displaystyle{v_t=((1-t)v_{0x}+tv_{1x},0)}$$

$$\displaystyle{w_t=(r_0(1-t)+tr_1)e^{i((1-t)\theta_0+t\theta_1)}}$$

Is the following inequality

$$\displaystyle{\frac{||v_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}||}\ge \frac{||v_{t_1}+w_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}+w_{t_0}||}}$$

verified for every $t_0,t_1\in [0,1],t_0<t_1$?

If the answer is no, I'm searching for additional conditions on $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2$ which will guarantee that this inequality is always verified.

---

My attempt: I've tried many examples without findind a counterexample. But I couldn't find a general proof.

Comment: What about the case $v_1=-w_1$ and $m=n=1$?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti You're right, there is a problem, I'll fix it

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to be asking about convex combinations, e.g., $v_t = (1-t)v_1 + t v_2$? I can't imagine why a deformation would be a linear combination in both magnitude and angle.

Comment: @adfriedman yes, I'm sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement (of the original question) is not true. Take $v_1=e^{2\pi i/3}=(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$, $v_2=e^{4\pi i/3}=(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)$, $w_0=w_1=(1,0)=e^0$.

Then

- $v_1$ and $w_1$ are linearly independent
- $v_2$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent
- the following inequalities are satisfied:
  $$\displaystyle{\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}=1\ge 1= \frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}}\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}=1\ge 1=\frac{||v_2+w_2||}{||v_1+w_1||}$$

For all $t$, we have $w_t=(1,0)$. For $t=1/4$ we have $v_t=e^{i((1-t)2\pi/3+t4\pi/3)}=e^{5\pi/6}=(-\sqrt{3}/2,1/2)$. Hence $v_t+w_t=(1-\sqrt{3}/2,1/2)$ and so $\|v_t+w_t\|=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}<1$. Set $t_1=1$ and $t_0=1/4$. Then
$$
\frac{||v_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}||}=1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}=\frac{||v_{t_1}+w_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}+w_{t_0}||}
$$

I don't see any conditions you can put on $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2$ such that the inequality is satisfied. What I did was to find the vectors such that you have equality for $t=0$ and for $t=1$. Then there must be an intermediate value where your inequality fails.

${\bf EDIT:}$
As for the second version of the question we also find a counterexample, that is, $v_0(v_{0x},0),v_1=(v_{1x},0),w_0,w_1$ such that

- $v_{0x}>0$ and $v_{1x}>0$
- $0<\theta_0<\pi$ and $0<\theta_1<\pi$
- the following inequalities are satisfied:

$$\displaystyle{\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}> \frac{||w_1||}{||w_0||}}\quad \textit{and }\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}> \frac{||v_1+w_1||}{||v_0+w_0||}$$

and such that for $t_1=1/2$ and $t_0=0$ we have

$$\displaystyle{\frac{||v_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}||}< \frac{||v_{t_1}+w_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}+w_{t_0}||}}$$
where

$$\displaystyle{v_t=((1-t)v_{0x}+tv_{1x},0)}$$

$$\displaystyle{w_t=(r_0(1-t)+tr_1)e^{i((1-t)\theta_0+t\theta_1)}}$$
with $\theta_1=\pi/2$ and $\theta_0=\pi/2+\arctan(5/\sqrt{299})$.

In fact, set $v_{0x}=4$, $v_{1x}=3.04$ $w_1=(0,2)$ and $w_0=\frac{2}{9}(-5,\sqrt{299})$.

Then $\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}=\frac 34+0.01=0.76$, $\frac{||w_1||}{||w_0||}=\frac 34$, and
$\frac{||v_1+w_1||}{||v_0+w_0||}=\frac{3\sqrt{13.2416}}{4\sqrt{13}}=0.756937...<0.76$.

But for $t_1=1/2$ and $t_0=0$ we have $||v_{t_1}||=3.52$, $||v_{t_0}||=4$, $||v_{t_0}+w_{t_0}||=\frac 43\sqrt{13}$, 
$||v_{t_1}+w_{t_1}||=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{85-84 \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{299}}\right)\right)}=4.27834...$

and so

$\frac{||v_{t_1}||}{||v_{t_0}||}=0.88$ and $\frac{||v_1+w_1||}{||v_0+w_0||}=0.889949...$, so the inequality is not satisfied.

The strategy for finding a counterexample was to find $v_0,v_1,w_0,w_1$ such that
$$(1)\quad\quad\quad\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}= \frac{||w_1||}{||w_0||}\quad \text{and}\quad\frac{||v_1||}{||v_0||}= \frac{||v_1+w_1||}{||v_0+w_0||},$$
then for all $t\in[0,1]$ we should have the inequalites
$$
\frac{||w_1+v_1||}{||v_1||}\le \frac{||w_t+v_t||}{||v_t||}\le \frac{||w_0+v_0||}{||v_0||}=\frac{||w_1+v_1||}{||v_1||},
$$
but we find some $t$ that doesn't satisfies the inequalites, and then disturb the initial data a bit, so that we have inequalities in (1) but the same $t$ still contradicts the desired conclusion.

This strategy takes advantage of the fact that the deformation is not very well behaved.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly your counterexample works only if the hypothesis inequalities are equalities. Then one could put the additional condition that the inequalities are strict: $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}> \frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}$ and $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}> \frac{||v_2+w_2||}{||v_1+w_1||}$. Would it still be not true?

Comment: No, you can sum small perturbations to the vectors in order to get strict inequalities, and the conclusion is still wrong. Taking the inequalities as equalities is just the easiest way to obtain counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand how these small perturbation should be applied in order to obtain a counter example for the strict inequalities. Consider the case $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}>\frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}>1$ and $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}>\frac{||w_2+v_2||}{||w_1+v_1||}>1$. Can you please write explicitly how can one obtain a counterexample?

Comment: For $\varepsilon$ small enough (for example $\varepsilon=1/100$) define $\bar v_2=v_2(1+2\varepsilon)$, $\bar w_2=w_2(1+\varepsilon)$. Then the inequalities are strict, and you get still a contradiction for $t=1/4$.

Comment: Thank you, it's clearer now. But if I understand correctly then does your counterexample work only for $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}$ and $\frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}$ close to 1? Can't we impose $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}$ and $\frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}$ to be $>>1$ to force my claim to work?

Comment: You probably have to add some limitations to the angles, in order to avoid $v_t+w_t=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. What I mean is this: you showed a counterexample for $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}>\frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}$ close enough to 1 (as you said, "for $\epsilon$ small enough.."). Now I'm asking: would there still be a counterexample for the strict inequalities in case $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}>\frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}$ are not close enough to 1? In other words, the additional condition we could add to make my claim work could be that $\frac{||v_2||}{||v_1||}>\frac{||w_2||}{||w_1||}$ are not close enough to 1

Comment: Maybe that would eliminate my counterexample. In general, you have to make some restrictions to the angles. The deformation you use that includes a convex combination of the angles is not well behaved, specially if you are working with the sum. So your only chance is to use continuity, and for that you have to restrict the range of the angles.

Comment: I've added a condition on the angles. May I ask you to update your answer?